# Reference for proof that consistency of $\omega_1$-Erdos cardinal implies Con(Chang's Conjecture)

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals

What is a good source for Silver's proof (or a more modern version) that Con($\exists \omega_1$-Erdos cardinal) implies Con(Chang's Conjecture)?

Silver's original proof seems to have never been published and I didn't find a proof in the set theory books I looked at (i.e. Jech's "Set Theory: the 3rd Millennium Edition" and Kanamori's "Higher Infinite")

Answer (score 7):

Some references:

1) K.  Kunen,  Saturated  ideals: The  consistency  of $(\omega_{n+2}, \omega_{n+1})\twoheadrightarrow (\omega_{n+1}, \omega_n)$  for  $n \geq 1$ has been  established starting with  a  huge  cardinal.

2)   H.-D. Donder and J.-P. Levinski,  Some  principles related  to  Chang's Conjecture: A proof is given without  use of Martin's Axiom,  and also using a Levy  collapse instead of 
a  Silver  collapse.

3) K. Devlin, A note on a problem of Erdos and Hajnal: A generalization of Silver's theorem is proved.

Answer (score 6):

A sketch of Silver's original argument appears in section 19 here: http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/e.pdf